# declaring a python variable in a list [data] = self.read()?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

while studying the open source repo of Odoo I found a line of code that I don't understand like the following

```py
[data] = self.read()
```

found there https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8f297c9d5f6d31370797d64fee5ca9d779f14b81/addons/hr_holidays/wizard/hr_holidays_summary_department.py#L25

I really would like to know why would you put the variable in a list

Comment: It's not a list, btw. There is no list object involved, it is just a particular syntax, equivalently, you could do `(data,) = self.read()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to ensure that `[data]` is an iterable of one item and therefore unpacks the first value from `self.read()`

It cannot be assigned to a non-iterable

```
>>> [data] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Works for iterable types, though must have a length equal to one

```
>>> [data] = {'some':2}
>>> data
'some'
>>> [data] = {'foo':2, 'bar':3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
>>> [data] = [1]
>>> data
1
>>> [data] = [[1]]
>>> data
[1]
>>> [data] = [1, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
>>> [data] = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)
```

Comment: But this can be achieved by using ```self.read()[:1]``` (assumming ```self.read()``` returns a list of items) if the concern is really on one value from an iterable.

Comment: That would return a list, though, not unpack it

Comment: @HenryTjhia `read` method returns a list of dictionaries mapping field names to their values, with one dictionary per record. In the example above, the `print_report` is supposed to be called from a button in the wizard which means `self` is a recordset of length 1 and the read method will return a list with one dict.